# Checking the status of Ansible processes

Tags: ansible

The machine I am targeting should, in theory, have a process running for each individual client called 'marketaccess {client_name}' and I want to ensure that this process is running. Ansible is proving very challenging for checking if processes are running. Below is the playbook I am trying to use to see if there is a process running on a given machine. I plan to then run a conditional on the 'stdout' and say that if it does not contain the customer's name then run a restart process script against that given customer. The issue is that when I run this playbook it tells me that the dictionary object has no attribute 'stdout' yet when I remove the '.stdout' it runs fine and I can clearly see the stdout value for service_status.

```
- name: Check if process for each client exists
  shell: ps aux | grep {{ item.key|lower }}
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: false
  register: service_status
  with_dict: "{{ customers }}"

- name: Report status of service
  debug:
    msg: "{{ service_status.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `service_status` is a result of a looped task, so it has `service_status.results` list which contains results for every iteration.

To see `stdout` for every iteration, you can use:

```
- name: Report status of service
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ service_status.results }}"
```

But you may want to read [this note](https://ansibledaily.com/idempotent-shell-command-in-ansible/) about idempotent shell tasks and rewrite your code with clean single task.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, Thank you for your advice. Would you be able to recommend a better way to write this playbook so that processes can be individually checked in a clean single task?